# How can I prevent changes in a variable in AsyncTask function

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, kotlin

I do some works in AsyncTask function, so my variable changes every time. but I want just one more my variable changes at first time, and no in the future.

Comment: Set a Boolean flag when you first change it?

Comment: Thanks, I solved that by using temp value and don't using reference variable!